# Backbone.js : can't get collection.get to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is so strange.

I do

```
console.log(this.collection);
```

And I can see all my models fine with its IDs attached correctly.

But on the same line, I do

```
console.log(this.collection.get(1));
```

And it tells me it's "undefined".

What's going on?

EDIT : Just wondering, does "id" have to be unique? I have some models that have no "ids" and then others have IDs set. Does this matter?

Comment: ID does have to be unique. Can you see if you can access a model with something like `console.log(this.collection.at(1));`

Comment: [`.get()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get) is getting model by `id` and [`.at()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-at) by the position in the collection. So there is no model with ID 1.

Comment: Is the ID a string:

`console.log(this.collection.get('1'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `at(1)` instead of `get(1)`, `get()` is looking for an element by id  in the collection while `at()` is looking at a position.